# Error "No se esperaba ELSE en este momento" en código de archivo .bat

Tags: windows, batch, windows10, .bat

Tengo **un par de dudas** referentes a unos códigos *.bat* que debo generar para que la **CMD** lleve a cabo una serie de acciones relacionadas con directorios.

A continuación os describo qué es lo que se me pidió:

> *"En la carpeta DOS, crea un fichero por lotes llamado tres.bat que admita como parámetro un nombre de archivo, y si existe, copie ese archivo en la carpeta UNO. Si no existe, debe dar un mensaje al usuario diciendo que ese archivo no existe en ese directorio".*

Las carpetas mencionadas se corresponden con los directorios situados en una **unidad flash** de la que dispongo (E:).

En este caso el código que he intentado utilizar es el siguiente:

```
if "%1" =="" (
            echo Introduza el nombre del archivo, por favor 
) else ( 
        IF EXIST "%1" E:\GonzálezCOPIA\DOS (
                echo se va a proceder a copiar el archivo %1%
                echo ...
                (copy %1 E:\GonzálezCopia\UNO)
                pause
                
) ELSE (

            echo El archivo %1 no existe
            
))
```

Tras introducir este código, el CMD arroja el error:

> ***"No se esperaba ELSE en este momento"***.

Desconozco dónde está el error y cuál sería el código correcto, pues llevo bastantes horas investigando y no hay manera.

A su vez me gustaría preguntaros qué código debería utilizar para generar un archivo *.bat* para realizar la siguiente tarea:

> *"En la carpeta DOS, crea un fichero por lotes, llamado uno.bat que pida al usuario un nombre de archivo, lo lea y diga si existe ese archivo dentro del directorio DOS."*

Comment: Recordá que debés hacer _una sola pregunta por vez_. En el caso de tu segunda "duda", debés poner un [repro] de lo que intentaste hasta el momento. Leé [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Batch no tiene `elif`, cada `if` solo puede tener un `else`; lo que si es que puede meter uno dentro de otro, también puedes gastar el `goto` pero lo va hacer muy difícil de leer si lo usas mucho

```
@echo off

:: /a convierte string a int

set /a var_a = 1
set /a var_b = 0

if %var_a% == 1 (

    if %var_b% == 1 (
        echo "var_b -> True"

    ) else (
        echo "var_b -> False"
    )

) else (
    echo "var_a -> False"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema aparentemente esta en la linea 4:
IF EXIST "%1" E:\GonzálezCOPIA\DOS (
esa sintaxis no es correcta. No me queda claro si necesitas saber si existe "%1" o E:\GonzálezCOPIA\DOS, o si queres comparar "%1" con E:\GonzálezCOPIA\DOS.

En lo personal, te recomiendo usar abstraciones de los parametros con nombres que hagan referencia a lgo especifico, como archivoOrigen, carpetaUno, datoDeEntrada, miArchivo, etc. en lugar de %1, %2, etc o dejes algun comentario o alguna asignacion de estas referencias para hacer mas claro el codigo. Eso te puede ayudar mas que nada en codigos mas extensos.

Para este requerimiento en particular:

> ***"En la carpeta DOS, crea un fichero por lotes llamado tres.bat que admita como parámetro un nombre de archivo, y si existe, copie ese
> archivo en la carpeta UNO. Si no existe, debe dar un mensaje al
> usuario diciendo que ese archivo no existe en ese directorio"***

se me ocurre esta opción, pero no es la única, ni la mejor, solo es una opción.

```
SET /P miArchivo= "Por favor, introduza el nombre del archivo a copiar: "

if exist %miArchivo%.* (
        copy /y %miArchivo%.* .\UNO\%miArchivo%.*
) else (
        echo El archivo "%miArchivo%" no existe en el directorio DOS
)
```

En caso de requerir la extencion del archivo en el parametro, habria que hacer algunas modificaciones, pero como lo lo aclara el requerimiento, asumo que debe mover cualquier archivo.

Comment: Tampoco me queda claro donde está ubicada la carpeta UNO. En caso de estar un nivel mas arriba, podrias anteponer un cd.. un linea antes del copy. El ./ indica la carpeta donde se corre el script tres.bat

Answer (score 0):

## Breve Explicación

Hay ciertos errores que estás cometiendo con tu código. El primero, es que no deberías escribir una condicional dentro de otra cuando se trata de batch.

El segundo error está en la segunda condicional (la encargada de comprobar si el archivo en cuestión existe).

Pues aparte de ser poco eficiente si es que se quiere ejecutar en un ordenador distinto o otra ruta, está mal escrito, en todo caso sería así.

```
if exist E:\GonzálezCOPIA\DOS\%1 (
)
```

### Explicación de la solución

Al tratarse de un script que debe ser ejecutado desde la terminal de windows simplemente deberías hacer que la condicional detecte si no hay un archivo. Si es que no lo hay se romperá la rutina del script y se le enviará un mensaje al usuario.

Después de esa condicional haremos otra más que detecte si existe, si existe lo copiará el la ubicación. Si no existe le devolverá un mensaje al usuario y romperá la rutina del script.

### Cómo ejecutar el script

Desde la terminal de windows, ubícate en la carpeta donde se encuentre el script y escribe

`tres.bat <Nombre del archivo>`

## Código

```
@echo off

REM Comprobamos si se ha ingresado un archivo
if "%1"=="" (
    echo Para poder ejecutar este codigo deberás introducir el nombre del archivo en cuestion.
    REM Rompe la rutina en caso de no har ingresado argumentos y devuelve al usuario a la terminal
    goto :eof
)

if exist %1 (
    echo Archivo localizado, copiando
    REM Después del /d deberás ingresar el destino de la copia, aun que si las carpeta 1 y 2 estan en la misma con eso te sirve.
    copy %1 /d "..\UNO" 
) else (
    echo El archivo mencionado no existe
    REM Rompe la rutina en caso de no existir y devuelve al usuario a la terminal
    goto :eof
)
```